# Getting CNLabeledValue error "'NSCopying & NSSecureCoding' cannot be in Xcode 10.2 not in Xcode 10.1

Tags: swift, cncontact

```
var currentContact = CNLabeledValue<NSCopying & NSSecureCoding>()
```

I want to create a variable which will store the value from the contact which can be either a phone number or an email address

```
var currentContact = CNLabeledValue<NSCopying & NSSecureCoding>()
currentContact = self.itemsInAcontact[section][0] as! CNLabeledValue


if ((currentContact.value as? CNPhoneNumber) != nil){
    phoneNumber = currentContact.value as! CNPhoneNumber

    if let y = phoneNumber?.value(forKey: "initialCountryCode"){
        cell.nameLabel!.text = "\(phoneNumber!.value(forKey: "initialCountryCode") as! String)\(phoneNumber!.stringValue)"
    }else{
        cell.nameLabel!.text = "\(phoneNumber!.stringValue)"
    }
}else{
    cell.nameLabel!.text = currentContact.value as! String
}
```

Here i am trying to display the contact number or email address available in a no name type contact inside the cell of a tableview, but I'm getting error on declaration of `var currenctContact`

The error message: "'NSCopying & NSSecureCoding' cannot be used as a type conforming to protocol 'NSSecureCoding' because 'NSSecureCoding' has static requirements".

Comment: You need to give the full error message which is "'NSCopying & NSSecureCoding' cannot be used as a type conforming to protocol 'NSSecureCoding' because 'NSSecureCoding' has static requirements".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LabeledValue is a generic. Two different LabeledValue types (that is, the same generic resolved in two different ways, `CNLabeledValue<NSString>` and `CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>`) are different types and cannot be stored in a common property. This is no different from the fact that `[Int]` and `[String]` are two different types even though they are both arrays.

The only way you can store two different LabeledValue types in a single property is to type that property as AnyObject. Thus, this works:

```
var currentContact : AnyObject? = nil

let phoneNumber = CNPhoneNumber(stringValue: "1234567890")
let labelled = CNLabeledValue(label: "yoho", value: phoneNumber)
currentContact = labelled

let email = CNLabeledValue(label: "hoha", value: "mickey@mouse.com" as NSString)
currentContact = email
```

However, I don’t recommend doing that. Instead, since all you really need is a string, make your `currentContact` a labeled value wrapping an NSString:

```
var currentContact : CNLabeledValue<NSString>? = nil
```

You can store an email CNLabeledValue directly into that. For a phone number, form a new labeled value from the phone number’s string value:

```
currentContact = CNLabeledValue(
    label:phone.label, value:phone.value.stringValue as NSString)
```

Comment: actually here i have to distinguish
1)  <CNLabeledValue: 0x600002681200: identifier=FE3049D0-3EDF-44D0-A280-872B6751FDEE, label=_$!<Home>!$_, value=anna-haro@mac.com>

from

2) <CNLabeledValue: 0x600002681a00: identifier=3CD5F927-B150-4104-918B-C26DD6AC811B, label=_$!<Main>!$_, value=<CNPhoneNumber: 0x600003d2d040: stringValue=(415) 555-3695, initialCountryCode=(null)>>

and represent appropriately, if i store a String in my model,  it works fine for emails but not for phone numbers

Comment: My answer still stands. You cannot store two different types in one variable. If you need to store emails and phone numbers that’s at least two variables, not just one.

Comment: You can transform the phone number into a `CNLabeledValue<NSString>`. That gives it a common type with the email labeled value, and you can store either of them in the same property. I’ve edited to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Apple changed something on NSSecureCoding in XCode 10.2 but I couldn't find any details yet.

So, for now, you should change from NSCopying & NSSecureCoding to NSString

```
var currentContact = CNLabeledValue<NSString>()
```

Comment: actually here i can get either:

1)  <CNLabeledValue: 0x600002681200: identifier=FE3049D0-3EDF-44D0-A280-872B6751FDEE, label=_$!<Home>!$_, value=anna-haro@mac.com>

or

2) <CNLabeledValue: 0x600002681a00: identifier=3CD5F927-B150-4104-918B-C26DD6AC811B, label=_$!<Main>!$_, value=<CNPhoneNumber: 0x600003d2d040: stringValue=(415) 555-3695, initialCountryCode=(null)>>

if i use the change u have suggested i can get email values correctly but in case of a CNPhoneNumber value it crashes